# Store or retrieve identifier from create-invalidation

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to create an invalidation request as

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id  XXXXXX --paths '/*'
```

and soon want to listen for it to complete using

```
aws cloudfront wait invalidation-completed --id <<NEED ID HERE>> --distribution-id XXXXXX && callback()
```

How to get the ID generated from invalidation request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Store the output of the create-invalidation command in a variable
invalidation_output=$(aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id XXXXXX --paths '/*')

# Extract the Invalidation ID using jq (make sure you have jq installed)
invalidation_id=$(echo $invalidation_output | jq -r '.Invalidation.Id')
```

Ref :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html#examples

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).